# Doubt concerning the use of in and by

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Consider the following sentences:

> The prevalent cases of mCNV are likely to rise from 250 in 2020 to reach 350 **in** 2030.

> The prevalent cases of mCNV are likely to rise from 250 in 2020 to reach 350 **by** 2030.

What is the fundamental difference in the above sentences and which one would you deem correct in this context?

Comment: In 2030, during that year, by 2030, before that year.

Comment: Would 'by 2030' include 2030 as well? As in, by the end of 2030?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey see my answer for an explanation of prevalence in medical contexts.

Comment: What do you know about the differences between "in" and "by"? What about the differences are you still confused by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, it is important to first explain the difference between [prevalence and incidence](https://sph.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/112/2015/07/nciph_ERIC1.pdf) in medical reporting.

> **Prevalence**
> In a study of prevalent cases of diabetes with a one year time period, anyone who has diabetes during the one year study period would be counted as a case.
> These prevalent cases would include both people who have diabetes at the outset of the study year as well as any who developed diabetes over the course of the study.

> **Incidence**
> For example, in a study of incident cases of diabetes with a one year
> time period, only those who developed diabetes over the course of the one year study period are considered incident cases.

I'll first answer your question assuming that the word was **Incident**.
"reach 350 by 2030" would mean that the total number of new cases for all the years from 2021 to 2030 will be 350. "... reach 350 in 2030" would mean that the number of new cases in 2030 alone will be 350.

Your sentence actually refers to prevalence of a condition called mCNV, which generally people don't die of, so people who develop the condition during 2021 to 2030 would, excluding deaths from natural causes, count as prevalent cases for the year 2030. The sentences with **by** and **in** therefore mean the same.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation, JavaLatte. So, as per your answer, in the context of prevalence, in 2030 and by 2030 are the same, right?

Comment: The phrase "likely to rise" indicates that you are are not guaranteeing that the predictions will exactly match actual figures. If you use the word "reach" it doesn't matter if the number of incident cases reaches 350 earlier, of the actual number of incident cases in 2030 exceeds 350.

Comment: Yes, in the context of prevalence, **in 2030** and **by 2030** are the same, because prevalence is cumulative.

Comment: From an analysis standpoint, if I have found incident cases of mCNV from 2020 to 2030, separately for each year, would it be wrong to write that the "incident cases are likely to rise from 250 in 2020 to 350 by 2030'?

Comment: taking out **to reach** seems to change that a little. If you predict incident cases for each year from 2020 to 2030, and incident cases will be 350 in 230,  you could make it completely clear by saying "**yearly** incident cases are likely to rise from 250 in 2020 to 350 by 2030'"

Comment: I have re-read your answer and understood that in 2030 and by 2030 are the same in the context of prevalence as it is cumulative, and in terms of incidence, it would differ if the incident cases are of a specific year or the entire period from 2021 to 2030. I apologize for asking a trivial question, but does it mean that if I have found the incident cases in 2030 to be 530, I should only use 'in 2030'? Also, could you explain why I shouldn't use reach once more? Thank you!

Comment: As long as you specify "**yearly** incidence figures", you can use **in** or **by**. I didn't say that you shouldn't use **reach**: I was simply commenting on the fact that the word was present in your original question but  you had omitted it from the sentence in your previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

- *350 in 2030*: the number will be 350 at some point in the year 2030 and not before
- *350 by 2030*: the number will be 350 or more at any point in the year 2030 or before

You should remove *reach*.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of prevalent in medical contexts.

Comment: From an analysis standpoint, if I have found a specific number of the prevalent cases for each year from 2020 to 2030, would it be correct to write that the number is likely to rise from 250 in 2020 to 2030 by 2030, considering that even if my analysis has shown 350 cases in 2030, the number could be reached in 2029 as well? Or, should I write that the cases are likely to rise from 250 in 2020 to 350 in 2030?

Comment: @JavaLatte: Thanks. It's gone.

Answer (score 0):

"The number of cases IS..."
or
"Cases (or case-numbers) ARE..."

You don't need "reach".

In/by are as Michael Harvey says.